# PropertyplaceholderConfigurer :properties file in WEB-INF not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jee

I have a typical eclipse based web-app structure project.I coded for backend for the application and wanted to test it.I am using spring IOC and hibernate in the backend.So , all the xml and properties file are located in WEB-INF.When I am trying to test the backend through a stand alone main method ,it is not able to find the properties file although the properties file and xml are loacted in the same folder i.e . WEB-INF.[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Probable cause is: outside a webapp "/WEB-INF" is a directory named `WEB-INF` at the root path (i.e. `/` under linux). As a workaround, it's possible to use multiple locations with the PPC

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `database.properties` to `/WEB-INF/classes/database.properties`, basically put it on the classpath, and access it as

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I am trying to run the backend using main method,where in I cannot get ServletContext.

Comment: oki, I've removed from the answer as it is not a viable solution for you. Placing the properties file on classpath and accessing it as a classpath resource should work for you, doesn't it?